# How to POST an image to a WebMethod using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, canvas, webmethod

I've an ASP.NET WebMethod like following.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void AddCameraImage(string imageArray)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

I'm reading an image from `canvas` and want to POST the image to the above method using following code:

```
$("#imageUl li").each(function (index, item) {
  console.log($(this).find("canvas")[0].toDataURL("image/png"));
  //This log is working properly. It's logging a very big string.  "data:image/png;base64,iVBORVl3APD/AwWGMo8iBuQmCC...."
  //I've truncated the string here.
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/AddCameraImage",
    data: '{ "imageArray": "' + $(this).find("canvas")[0].toDataURL("image/png") + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
       },
    failure: function (response) {
          alert("Failed to add image");
       }
    });
 });
```

But it's showing `POST http://localhost:1315/Default.aspx/AddCameraImage 500 (Internal Server Error)`

But if I change the `data` property of ajax request to `data: '{ "imageArray": "' + "test_hardcode_data" + '"}',`, it's working properly.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Try to pass data like this - `data: '{ "imageArray": "' + $(this).find("canvas")[0].toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")`

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase the maxJsonLength in the web.config. If I remember well the default is around 100k, probably not enough for your pic.
And also change "failure: function (response) {" in "error: function (a,b,c) {", set a breakpoint inside and check the content of the 3 variables, it should tell you about the size limit error.